# Getting errors on Activity change?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-xml

I have this code:

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, errors, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        // Success! Cache the inputs and continue with registration.
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("name", name);
        editor.putString("email", email);
        editor.putString("password", password);

        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                sendRegisterActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
```

Now, this is within a `public void sendRegistration(View view)` which is fired on the click of a button. Whenever I take away the last 3 lines of the "else" statement it works. But when I add it, I get "Source could not be found". sendRegisterActivity.java exists but still I'm getting errors. This is how sendRegisterActivity looks:

```
public class sendRegisterActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sendregister);
    }
}
```

sendregister.xml is within the "layout" folder, and is completely valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added sendRegisterActivity to your manifest?

Comment: I missed that out! I did it for my last acitvity but forget that step this time. Thanks, I feel so dumb :P

Comment: Hah, I do that _all_ the time